# Django 1.11, not displaying data in template

Tags: python, django

I've a simple model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='+')
    name_task = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    label_task = models.ManyToManyField(LabelTask)
    executive_man = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

But in a template, unable to render all data, for example, code from views look like

```
def task_detail(request, pk):
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'task/task_detail.html', {'task': task})
```

And template look like

```
<small>{{ task.author }}</small>
<h1>{{ task.name_task }}</h1>
<p>Label - {{ task.label_task }}</p>
<p>Executive - {{ task.executive_man }}</p>
```

But all data show good, but Label - `task.LabelTask.None`
Executive - `auth.User.None`

I do not right it.
Label - instead of data is the `task.LabelTask.None`
Executive - instead select users - `auth.User.None`
But in my admin look all good.
Hope you help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: try to fetch data with: `{{ task.label_task_set.all.0 }}` cuz labeltask - is a Many-to-Many field, it contains a nested QuerySet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because these fields are `ManyToManyField`,
to access them, you need to do so with `all` in templates, `all()` in python codes

```
p>Label - {{ task.label_task.all }}</p>
<p>Executive - {{ task.executive_man.all }}</p>
```

Or you can loop through them

```
p>Label - 
      {% for label in task.label_task.all %}
        {{label}} {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
      {% empty %}
           No label tasks
      {% endfor%}</p>

<p>Executive - {% for man in task.executive_man.all %}
        {{man}} {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
      {% empty %}
           No Men
      {% endfor%}</p>
```

Comment: thanks. `&}` - I think it an error-typo and `if no` too.